# Solving TypeError bug in sqrt function Python

Tags: python, debugging, math, distance, sqrt

So I have this code, and I receive an error when I try to use that Math library's sqrt function for the distance formula.

Can someone help me solve this TypeError?

```
import math

def isCollision(basketX, basketY, appleX, appleY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(basketX - appleX, 2)) + (math.pow(basketY - appleY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


collision = isCollision(basketX[i], basketY[i], appleX, appleY)
        if collision:
            score_value += 1
            appleX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            appleY[i] = random.randint(0, 150)
```

This is the error I am receiving (NOTE: This is a small part of a much bigger code, that is why it says line 101) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shaha/PycharmProjects/ApplePicker/main.py", line 101, in <module>
    collision = isCollision(basketX[i], basketY[i], appleX, appleY)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. The error message is telling you either `basketX` or `basketY` is an *integer*.

Comment: I'd recommend to us a debugger or just to print values of `basketX` and `basketY` before calling isCollision. IMHO the cause of error is outside this fragment of code.

Answer (score 0):

`basketX` and `basketY` seem to be of type `int` instead type `list`, therefore you cannot access any information via `basketX[i]` or `basketY[i]`.

Try to pass `basketX` and `basketY` directly to the function.

Comment: Also, you will most likely run into errors again when doing this:
`appleX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)` and `appleY[i] = random.randint(0, 150)`
as `appleX` and `appleY` seem to be of type `int` as well.